# What does the crested logo with a stacked "A C and I" on this Baldwin-Felts certificate mean?

Tags: united-states, government, law-enforcement

I was watching a PBS documentary [The Mine Wars](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/americanexperience/films/theminewars/#part01)(25:30) where the Baldwin-Felts Detective Agency is discussed. I noticed this crested logo which looks like it says “CIA Police” and was curious what it means and what organization it may reference.

[image: baldwin-felts detective agency 1]
[image: baldwin-felts detective agency 2]
[image: baldwin-felts detective agency 3]

Comment: Could it be "International Association Chiefs (of) Police" as listed on the right hand side?

Comment: @SteveBird Ah, good catch. Want to make an answer?

Comment: I added a timestamp and additional caps, also updated the question to include the stacked letters in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stacked A, C and I logo (over the word police) would appear to be the logo for the [International Association of Chiefs of Police](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Association_of_Chiefs_of_Police). This is listed on the right hand side of the document as the "International Association Chiefs of Police". The organisation was founded in May 1893 and is [still in operation](https://www.theiacp.org/) with a slightly modified logo.

A History of the evolution of the IACP insignia is [here](https://www.policechiefmagazine.org/history-iacp-insignia/) but this was written in 1994 before the recent transition to the latest logo.

Comment: https://www.offdutyservices.com/  http://shsucj.blogspot.com/2015/02/dr-king-appointed-to-iacp-policy-board.html

Comment: The two logos I linked look so incredibly 1930s https://www.picclickimg.com/d/l400/pict/301231413995_/Vintage-June-1945-Certificate-International-Association-of-Chiefs.jpg Any chance you can dig up the date they modernised it from the one OP showed?

Comment: I'm guessing the current logo is fairly recent since the the modern version of the overlapping IAC logo is shown as 'in use' on the [Brands of the World website](https://www.brandsoftheworld.com/logo/iacp-international-association-of-chiefs-of-police).

Comment: The detail catching my eye is the tie at the base of the wreath. From your latest link I conclude that between 35 & 88 it went from realistic to abstract/stylised? As a copyrighted logo then, that info must be out there as well ;)